# Using Dublin Core to mark up pdf files

Tags: database, metadata, markup, dublin-core

Hey I am new to using dublin core and have been assigned a task to map some data, which is mostly pdf files (mostly lecture notes) into dublin core. I have no idea where to or how to get started. I read the dublin core documentation but it did not give me an idea of how to get started? I would like for someone who has worked with this before to please outline the process for me, or at least point me to a more descriptive resource about dublin core than the main dublin core website which doesn't do a good job of explaining the process at all.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the end, dc.dot will assign dublin core automatically to a document.  [DC dot, ukoln](http://www.ukoln.ac.uk/metadata/dcdot/)

Bear in mind the usual caveat with automated metadata - it is not normally as good as human generated metadata.

Going up a level, 
With regard to manual generation, the first thing to determine is what properties of the resource you want to define, eg. title, and what properties you don't.

Going up another level, why do you need to use DC at all?